# Phase name inside custom terraform data source

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to get terraform (v 0.13) phase name (apply, refresh, update) inside custom terraform data source?
Somewhere here:

```
func CustomSourceRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `update` there? And what are you trying to achieve? [`refresh` will just update the state file with any drift in the provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42630201/2291321) by reading the resources and data sources and an apply for a data source will also just read the data source so they should be doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A data source implementation is expected to behave identically regardless of at which point in the process Terraform reads it. There is no supported way to vary the behavior depending on whether the read happens at plan time or at apply time.